# Modifying a copy of an existing project and deploying that project updates the original project as well Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, ssis, project, ssis-2016

I have a SSIS project which I want to copy the existing code, forms, etc. from which is present in the project and simply make some adjustments to the existing code within. This is in order to adjust the code for another customer.

However, copying the solution files etc. from our shared harddrive to my local harddrive and making adjustsments in the code within that newly created project, still make the same updates on the original project's code.

How can I prevent this from happening? Do I need to rebuild the whole solution, or is there a better way to create a separate project using the structure, code and Windows forms of an existing one?

Comment: I think somethings going wrong with the copy- if you've truly copied it to your local harddrive, it would only be changing the versions in your local harddrive. maybe the project file in your local harddrive is pointing with absolute filenames to the shared harddrive?

Answer (score 0):

The most reliable way would be to create a project template or package templates and create a new project and solution. I always had a hard time just copying visual studio projects to adjust code for a new customer. You can find a description on how to create a project template [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xkh1wxd8.aspx) and a package [here](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2841/creating-ssis-package-templates-for-reusability/). I would personally go with package templates because this approach is more agile and can benefit in the future.